# Arrow functions are sometimes confusing. What happens if you omit return statement

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Today I found a issue in my code with arrow functions that drove me completely crazy.

I thought that this:

```
 classMethod = (param1, param2) =>
    this.APImethod(param1, param2);
```

was equivalent to this:

```
classMethod = (param1, param2) =>
    {this.APImethod(param1, param2)}
```

Comment: FWIW, arrow functions in Java, Swift etc. behave the same - `x->foo()` means `x->{return foo()}` (Java syntax). It's fairly standard and comes from the Haskell family of languages which was inspired by one of the syntax for functions in mathematics

Comment: Oh thanks. I wasn't aware that other languages have the same behavior. Kind of make sense. I'm only fluent with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

But no.
This:

```
 classMethod = (param1, param2) =>
    this.APImethod(param1, param2);
```

is omitting a return statement. The function is returning "this.APImethod(param1,param2)", meanwhile

```
classMethod = (param1, param2) =>
    {this.APImethod(param1, param2)}
```

Doesn't return anything, because if you type the { }, you need to specify the return statement.
The equivalent function would be:

```
classMethod = (param1, param2) =>
    {return this.APImethod(param1, param2)}
```

Hope this is useful for somebody.